# How to convert hexadecimal to double in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, hex, decimal

Currently, I am trying to use convert a hexadecimal string to a double. For background, I sending a number such as **2.0** through bluetooth to receive a byte array such as `[0,0,0,64]`. From there I tried to converting it to a hexadecimal using `hex.encode()`, and I received `00000040`.

At this point, I have been trying to find a method or function in flutter/dart to swap the endianess of the hexadecimal and mainly convert the hexadecimal to a double. I have tried dart functions such as `double.parse()` and `double.tryParse()`, but it does not seem to have options to add radix parameters to help designate that the string is a hexadecimal like `int.tryParse()`.

Mainly, I need a method to convert the hexadecimal to a double. Any useful help would be appreciated.

Edit: This is the code I am trying to work on ByteData with and running into issues. I am using this example make sure that I somehow change the incoming byte arrays into doubles for later use in calculations.

```
    return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
      stream: characteristic.value,
      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final value = snapshot.data; 

        print('test1'); print(value);
        print('test2'); var test2 = hex.encode(value); print(test2);

        print('test3'); var test3 = ByteData(4); test3.setInt8(0, value); test3.getFloat32(0, [Endian endian = Endian.little]); print(test3);
```

Comment: tried `ByteData`? the docs say: *"A fixed-length, random-access sequence of bytes that also provides random and unaligned access to the fixed-width integers and floating point numbers represented by those bytes. ByteData may be used to pack and unpack data from external sources (such as networks or files systems), and to process large quantities of numerical data more efficiently than would be possible with ordinary List implementations. ByteData can save space, by eliminating the need for object headers, and time, by eliminating the need for data copies."*

Comment: @pskink Mainly im getting two errors that prevent me from using ByteData: <List>Object cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'Endian' and <List>int cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. More information on the code is the in the orignal post above.

Comment: `import 'dart:typed_data';
void main() {
  var bd = ByteData(4);
  bd.setUint8(0, 0x41);
  bd.setUint8(1, 0x48);
  bd.setUint8(2, 0);
  bd.setUint8(3, 0);
  var f = bd.getFloat32(0);
  print(f);
  bd.setUint32(0, 0x41480000);
  var f1 = bd.getFloat32(0);
  print(f1);
}`